# Qt splash screen not shown in python

Tags: python, linux, qt, splash-screen

I'm trying to add an splash screen to my program, coded in python 2.7 and using pyqt4 libraries. My main file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from logindialog import LoginDialog
from mainwindow import MainWindow
import time
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        mw = MainWindow()

        # Create and display the splash screen
        splash_pix = QPixmap('images/sherlock_splash.png')
        splash = QSplashScreen(splash_pix, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        splash.setMask(splash_pix.mask())

        # adding progress bar
        progressBar = QProgressBar(splash)
        # adding message
        splash.showMessage('Discovering Nodes...', Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom, Qt.darkRed)

        splash.show()
        app.processEvents()

        for i in range(0, 100):
            progressBar.setValue(i)
            # Simulate something that takes time
            time.sleep(0.1)

        splash.close()

        # Show main window
        mw.show()
        app.exec_()
    except Exception:
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.exit(0)
```

I've coded it using Pycharm IDE. If I run it using pycharm RUN functionality the splash screen is shown up properly, however if I run it in linux command line (./main.py) it does not show up splash screen when I start my application.

Anybody could help me?

Thanks a lot!

**UPDATE & FIX**

```
...
# Create and display the splash screen
image_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
splash_pix = QPixmap('/'.join([image_path, 'images/sherlock_splash.png']))
splash = QSplashScreen(splash_pix, Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your project structure and be sure if the relative path to your `.png` file is correct

`'images/sherlock_splash.png'` when running from command line.

Also add following checking

```
if splash_pix is not None:
    ...
```

Comment: OMG! You're absolute right, it was my mistake, the path is wrong. Many many thanks!